# spring.cloud.config.server.git.basedir is shared

Tags: spring-cloud

My git based config service is serving configs based on different labels.

Looks like the basedir on the config server is shared across labels.

Looks like it overwrites basedir contents based on the most recent client request.

Anyway i can subdir (the basedir) based on labels ?
Won't subdir be more efficient ?

Comment: There is currently no way to 'subdir' the basedir for labels. It won't currently be more efficient, because each request to config server re-clones (or pulls) from git each time. What it could do, is make it so if the git server was unreachable, it could send the cached label. Otherwise it might not have anything to send. Feel free to file an issue or submit a pull request.

Comment: Ok, thanx,  I give the pull request a shot.